# Insert a php variable into my html url

Tags: php, get

Hi I am trying to add my php variable $remove into the query string so that when the submit button is pushed the action that happens is a request made to remove_friend_db.php?user=
where user = contained the value of $remove.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row())
{
    echo "<img src='images/$row[0]_thumb.jpg' atl='userThumbnail'>";
    echo "$row[1] $row[2] $row[3]";
    $remove= $row[0];
    ?>
    <form method="GET" action="remove_friend_db.php?remove="<?php "$remove">"">
    <input type="submit" value="Remove Friend">
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: `$remove` is aways blank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<?php echo $remove ?>`... You're not outputting anything. you're just basically saying "here's a variable" and php's going "ok, whatever".

Comment: actualy there's a syntax error or two around there, but this is funny :)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you are using this technique.
If you want to use Form then make a input field and then send it to the file.

```
<form method="GET" action="remove_friend_db.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="" id="" value="<?php echo $remove; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Remove Friend">
</form>
```

Comment: But `type="text" name=""`would show up a text field in the html form.

Comment: Make it hidden type="hidden"

Answer (score 2):

You should also be able to do it via an hidden input field. Something like this should work ...

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row())
{
    echo "<img src='images/$row[0]_thumb.jpg' atl='userThumbnail'>";
    echo "$row[1] $row[2] $row[3]";
    $remove= $row[0];
  ?>
    <form method="GET" action="remove_friend_db.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="remove" value="<?php $remove ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Remove Friend">
    </form>
  <?php
}
```

Comment: `$remove` is not inside `php` tags, it will print as is. $remove

Comment: @AlexAndrei yes you're absolutely right. Fixed it in the answer. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on short tags (in php.ini), which are great for templating, you can do the following:

`value="<?=$remove?>"`